# What kind of 3.5mm extension cables are compatible with Apple EarPods?

Tags: audio, headphones, ear-phones

I bought a pair of [Apple 3.5mm EarPods](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MNHF2AM/A/earpods-with-35-mm-headphone-plug?fnode=e7fa962fb520f74ff2f48421366d1582af4810059821d4066a1898272dfe1ef15dc60de25bedc2737d8463b7142028554979c14e46621586f04ae2489c80d053d114d869f101b2ccb2aaaa1aeb0dc582e063f9ad44e19ad81d2a789f08d872df), but the cable is a bit too short.  I'd like to buy an extension cable, but I'm unsure what kind of cable I need to buy that will maintain all of the EarPods' features, specifically:

- Audio
- Microphone
- Remote controls (volume controls, playback controls, answer/end calls, Siri, etc.)

I'm assuming a basic extension cable like this won't work, since my EarPods have three rings on the plug and this extension cable only has two:

[image: A basic extension cable]

Will any extension cable with three rings work?  For example:

[image: A extension cable with three rings]

Comment: You need a 3.5mm headphone extension cable that has a 4 poles, just like the EarPods have, male to female stereo jack audio cable headset extension cable for all features of the EarPods to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [four pole 3.5 mm TRRS jack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#PDAs_and_mobile_phones) for full compatibility. You’ll lose mic and likely control with the three pole extension but sound should still play.

The spacing is the same (three insulator rings spaced every 1/8 inch apart). Disrgard that signaling using the four conductors isn’t a global standard since his extension just passes the signal between devices.

[image]

See some great technical discussions and a comparison of TRS vs TRRS to match your excellent photos of the extensions.

- [Can I use non-apple headphones with an iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135967/can-i-use-non-apple-headphones-with-an-iphone)