# How Apple EarPods send the volume up/down signal?

Tags: iphone, headphones, camera, microphone

I am trying to trigger an iPhone's camera with my own development board. I figured it out volume up/down signal is trigging the iPhone's camera, but I managed it at an Android device with touching an 220R or 600R resistor from mic pin to gnd pin. iPhone didn't even recognize my board as a headphone.

A 10K resistor from mic pin to gnd pin gives me the recognition as a headphone for iPhone but touching an 220R or 600R resistor from mic pin to gnd pin does nothing.

I noticed there is a 2.4V between mic and gnd pins and when volume up/down event happens this voltage drops to 2.2V.

Comment: Which connector are you using, Lightning or 30pin?

Comment: It's only 3.5mm jack

Comment: Are you taking the [different pin layouts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135967/can-i-use-non-apple-headphones-with-an-iphone) into account?

Comment: Yes, i know mic and gnd pin is different at Apple.